# Views Contextual filter: php code for getting the value from url

Tags: views

Im trying to set up a Contextual filter in drupal views based on the URL.

The contextual filter is operating with a text field that sets the node alias.

I have it working with "RAW value from URL" based on the position (parentpage/childpage/grandchild-page), but the position could change (only parents and child for example), so do i need to use the "PHP code", or is there a better way?

What i want to happen:

"If last section of page url, (grandchild-page), matches field set in contextual filter, then true (show fields).

Comment: I think you can just give it the arg number. Eg: mysite.com/foo/bar/baz has 3 args: 0=foo, 1=bar, 2=baz.

Comment: Maybe this will help: [Get last parameter of url in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11257994/get-last-parameter-of-url-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Though the solution you have implemented worked but my suggestion is to use the [request_uri()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/request_uri/7) instead of the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` because of the following reasons:

- `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is only available on Apache, whereas `request_uri()` generate an equivalent using other environment variables.
- Apache does nothing by default to sanitize the `$_SERVER` variables so directly using it without passing through the `check_plain` should be considered unsafe.

So its better to get the URL like this:

> $current_url = check_plain(request_uri());

Example: if the url is `http://www.example.com/param1/param2/param3` than the `$current_url` will contain `/param1/param2/param3`.

Rest you can build the logic to get the last params, there are numerous ways of doing that.

Comment: Thank you! I thought there might be a better drupal way of getting the url.

Comment: @petergus Always welcome. If it worked for you than pls. accept the answer so that it may others looking for the same.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to use PHP code - there is a module for that:
https://www.drupal.org/project/views_contextual_filter_query

OR you could use Context: https://www.drupal.org/project/context_query_param

Answer (score 0):

Thank you J. Reynolds for pointing me in the right direction!

I have used the following in "When the filter value is NOT available > provide a default argument > PHP Code"

```
$url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$url_path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$basename = pathinfo($url_path, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
return $basename;
```

($basename is matching the last segment of the URL which is set via pathauto from a custom pseudo title field on my content type, and this field is also used the operational contextual filter in Views.)

[image]

EDIT: I also have a Relationship "Content referencing Content from field_related_products" that is selected in the contextual filter.

*Please refer to the answer from Ankit Agrawal for a better way to retrieve the URL*